# What should the name of our main chatroom be?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, chat

Every Stack Exchange site (Not all) main chatroom has a unique name that is related to the main site itself.

for Example:

- Super User: Root Acess
- Gaming: The Bridge
- IoT: Chat of Things
- Unix & Linux: /dev/chat

and etc

What should our main chat room be named?

[The Real Essential Questions of Every Beta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/223675/311917)

> 5. Whats an interesting name for the chat room?
>      Every site comes with its official chat room. This is created automatically and can be reached from the Site Switcher on the top left. The chat room is the third place of your community, after main and meta. It is like the lounge where everybody can get together to discuss, complain and have fun. Personalizing this space to reflect your community and what you are, is one of the small steps to take towards building an active and engaged community.
>      Try to get a few ideas up, discuss and vote on them. The name could be something esoteric in your field, or something that every person may understand. Whichever it may be, go ahead and start the discussion!

Answer (score 7):

I'm all for the name *Droning on* or some variation thereof. Derived from [@TinkeringBell's suggestion in the room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/54084627#54084627).

Comment: Droning sounds good! let's wait for other suggestions too.

Answer (score 4):

How about *The Aerial View*? Fits the motif

Answer (score 3):

All good responses so far.

Seeing that we all want to fly drones, I am going to suggest that we call the chat room: **The Cockpit**.

Comment: I just checked - Aviation has the Hangar, so we don't clash :-)

Comment: Actually, _The Flow_ might be a good name!

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm...

What is this site about? Flying, in effect.

Let’s name the chat room **Fly Zone**!